# Get filtered alphanumeric values from array like alphanumeric values between range

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

How do I get filtered alphanumeric values from array like alphanumeric values between range.

```
$array1 = array("F6B10471", "A6A10471", "B6C10471", "D6A10471");
```

This is my Array I am going to pass the range between **A6A10471** to **D6A10471** My expected result is`Array([0] => A6A10471[1] => B6C10471[2] => D6A10471)`

Comment: So `strcmp` values with range edges.

Comment: Did you found solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using [base_convert](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php). Convert base from `36` to `10` and check like this

```
<?php
    $arr = array("F6B10471", "A6A10471", "B6C10471", "D6A10471");
    $start = base_convert("A6A10471",36,10);
    $end = base_convert("D6A10471",36,10);
    $new = array();
    foreach($arr as $val){
      $value = base_convert($val,36,10);
      if($value >= $start && $value <= $end ){
        $new[] = $val;    
      }
    }
    print_r($new);
?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/865289

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => A6A10471
    [1] => B6C10471
    [2] => D6A10471
)
```

Answer (score 1):

example of using [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a filter class, this can easily be updated if you want to implement a [Strategy Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

```
<?php
class FilterBetween
{
    private $start;
    private $end;

    public function __construct($start, $end)
    {
        $this->start = $start;
        $this->end = $end;
    }

    public function filter($value)
    {
        $result = false;
        if ($value >= $this->start && $value <= $this->end) {
            $result = true;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}


$arr = array("F6B10471", "A6A10471", "B6C10471", "D6A10471");

$objFilterBetween = new FilterBetween('A6A10471', 'D6A10471');
$arrResult = array_filter($arr, [$objFilterBetween, 'filter']);

var_dump($arrResult);
```

Comment: Thank you Wee Zel.